# Check if there is a key which has a specific value in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array here:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
     [id] => 1
     [message] =>
     [pinned] => 0
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
     [id] => 3
     [message] =>
     [pinned] => 1
  )
)
```

Now I've a problem. I need to check in this array if one of the keys **[pinned]** in this array contains the value `1`.

If this can be answered true, I want to do something. If not, do the next thing. This is a try but it's not working:

```
if (isset($my_array(isset($my_array->pinned)) === 1) {
    //One value of the pinned key is 1
} else {
    //No value of the pinned key is 1 -> skip
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array_reduce`:

```
if (array_reduce($my_array, function ($c, $v) { return $c || $v->pinned == 1; }, false)) {
    //One value of the pinned key is 1
} else {
    //No value of the pinned key is 1 -> skip
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1nG6L)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to iterate over the array and test each object individually. You can do that with a plain loop or `array_filter` for example:

```
$pinnedItems = array_filter($my_array, function($obj) {
  return $obj->pinned === 1;
});
if (count($pinnedItems) > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic loop through the array

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
  if($arr[$i]->pinned==1){
     // it is pinned - do something

  }else{
     // it isn't pinned - do something else/nothing

  }
}
```

If you wish to do nothing if it isn't pinned, just leave off the `else{}` completely

Answer (score 1):

```
    $tmpArray = array(
    array("one", array(1, 2, 3)),
    array("two", array(4, 5, 6)),
    array("three", array(7, 8, 9))
);

foreach ($tmpArray as $inner) {

    if (is_array($inner)) {
        foreach ($inner[1] as $key=>$value) {
           echo $key . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use $key to find it. Or use

```
$key = array_search ('your param', $arr);
```

to find what you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Use a search() function to hunt for the desired attribute in each object, then check the result. This is raw code, it could be written 10 times better, but it is just to get the idea.

```
<?php
$my_array = [
0 => (object) [
    'id' => 1,
    'message' => 'msg1',
    'pinned' => 0
],
1 => (object) [
    'id' => 3,
    'message' => 'msg3',
    'pinned' => 1
  ],
];

/**
 * Search in array $arrayVet in the attribute $field of each element (object) the value $value
 */
function search($arrayVet, $field, $value) {
    reset($arrayVet);
    while(isset($arrayVet[key($arrayVet)])) {
        if($arrayVet[key($arrayVet)]->$field == $value){
            return key($arrayVet);
        }
        next($arrayVet);
    }
    return -1;
}

$pinnedObject = search($my_array, 'pinned', 1);
if($pinnedObject != -1) {
    //One value of the pinned key is 1
    echo $my_array[$pinnedObject]->message;
} else {
    //No value of the pinned key is 1 -> skip
    echo "not found";
  }
?>
```

Comment: A bit to heavy for me but it works! Thank you too for your help!